# Transferring date to datagrid

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I defined a column in database like yyyy/mm/dd hh:hh:hh. Now, I want to transfer the data that I get from Visual Studio by datetimepicker to datagridview. Is there any way to do that?

This is the code that I wrote but I get an error from this line " ("select * from tablo where tablo.tarih >= '" + dtpBaslangic.Value.ToShortDateString() "

```
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
{

);

adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tablo where tablo.tarih >= '" + dtpBaslangic.Value.ToShortDateString() + "' AND tablo.tarih <= '" + dtpBaslangic.Value.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy") + "'" + " 23:59:59'", baglanti);

DataSet gonder = new DataSet();
try
{
    baglanti.Open();
    adp.Fill(gonder);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = gonder.Tables[0];
    baglanti.Close();
    adp.Dispose();
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Kayıtlar Listelenemedi!", "Hata", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? Compiler? Runtime? What does it say?

Comment: You are putting the closing quote too early  `AND tablo.tarih <= '" + dtpBaslangic.Value.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy") + " 23:59:59'", baglanti);`

Comment: You have 1 too much apostrophe there `dtpBaslangic.Value.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy")  + "'"`

Comment: What is  `hh:hh:hh` ? And please when storing dates use date columns not strings. Your query will never work correctly

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the line you are having problems with:

```
adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tablo where tablo.tarih >= '" + dtpBaslangic.Value.ToShortDateString() + "' AND tablo.tarih <= '" + dtpBaslangic.Value.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy") + "'" + " 23:59:59'", baglanti);
```

I would update it to use parameters:

```
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tablo where tablo.tarih >= @StartDateTime AND tablo.tarih <= @EndDateTime", baglanti);

adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDateTime", Convert.ToDateTime(dtpBaslangic.Value));

DateTime EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpBaslangic.Value);
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(23, 59, 0);
EndDate = EndDate.Date + ts;

adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDateTime", EndDate);
```

Comment: Valid point Steve, I had misread it as a datepicker. For the first one the 00:00:00 could just be dropped off. (I will update the code above).

Comment: Well, the ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") could solve as well, but the biggest problem here is the column `tarih` as string. What happen if I have two rows with values `01/03/2014 ...` and `20/05/2014 ...` and search for any date between `01/03/2014 00:00:00` and `31/03/2014 23:59:00`? This is a basic problem when you treat dates as formatted strings. (At least if you store the date in a string format like `yyyyMMddyymmss` you could use string comparison, but wait.... no, no, scratch it. Dates should be stored as dates)

Comment: Could always add a CAST to the SQL statement for the DateTime columns. (i.e. CAST(tablo.tarih AS datetime))

Comment: I would say "a remedy worse than the disease". Now you are removing any possible optimization if there is an index on the column. However, nothing to worry about, it is not a life or death decision, just bad code.